# Java File Movement Based on JSON Data

Tags: java, json, swing

I have a program that output the directory structure as JSON. I use the JSON data to bring up the tree representation of directory structure in my Java Swing Program.

Sample JSON Data :

```
{
    "path": "src/modules/abc/module",
    "name": "module",
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "src/modules/abc/module/controllers",
            "name": "controllers",
            "type": "folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "src/modules/abc/module/controllers/abc-module-controller.js",
                    "name": "abc-module-controller.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "src/modules/abc/module/layouts",
            "name": "layouts",
            "type": "folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "src/modules/abc/module/layouts/abc-layout.js",
                    "name": "abc-layout.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "src/modules/abc/module/routes",
            "name": "routes",
            "type": "folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "src/modules/abc/module/routes/abc-module-router.js",
                    "name": "abc-module-router.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "src/modules/abc/module/templates",
            "name": "templates",
            "type": "folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "src/modules/abc/module/templates/layout.hbs",
                    "name": "layout.hbs",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "path": "src/modules/abc/module/templates/links.hbs",
                    "name": "links.hbs",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "src/modules/abc/module/views",
            "name": "views",
            "type": "folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "src/modules/abc/module/views/links-view.js",
                    "name": "links-view.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Java Swing based tree is drag and droppable, meaning that users can use to rearrange the folder and file structure.( Only rearrange allowed, no addition, deletion or duplication of files/folder)

Now once rearrange complete, users can save the data as JSON.

I want to use the modified JSON and rearrange the actual physical files and folder.

say for eg: if a file "useful.file" originally present under folder "Paris" and customer using Swing did a drag and drop to another folder say "London" then i have to copy the file("useful.file") from paris folder to London folder.

I followed copy program given in oracle java site

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java

and able to copy from a source to destination, but i want to use the JSON content as input to do the rearrange.

I like to know, what is the proper way to do

1) Read original JSON and modified JSON, find the delta and then move files?

2) use Modified JSON as input without worrying about the Original JSON details

I can walk through the JSON with help of program like this [How do you tree walk JSON via Jackson 2 JsonNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526030/how-do-you-tree-walk-json-via-jackson-2-jsonnode)

but it's getting complex to walk and use the input to do the rearrange of physical files via copy program.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can the user create or remove folders? Can files be added or deleted or duplicated?

Comment: Thanks Eric for asking the right questions. No only movement of existing folder/files allowed. No Addition, deletion or duplication.

Comment: Just to be sure: do all the files have unique names? (So you can unambiguously identify each file by its name, regardless of its path?)

Comment: the name of the file can be anything - its unique per file, but another path can have the same file name....it always ends with .js or .hbs extension.....folder name also can be anything and its unique. similar to our windows folder and file convention.

Comment: Well then isn't that a problem? If you have two files with the same name, how can your be sure the user hasn't switched them with drag&drop? You would need to add a unique identifier to each file included in the JSON data.

Comment: Make the implementation simpler by enriching the source instead of figuring out what happened afterwards: include a "moved-from-path" in the modified JSON for files that were moved by the user. That way you only need to take action for files that have a "moved-from-path" attribute.

Comment: Good Question Eric, then probably for sake of simplicity let's assume all file names are unique regardless of paths.

Comment: @vanOekel. Thanks for your suggestion.Let me try that angle too.

Answer (score 1):

So based on your inputs I see three leads:

**1 - If unique file names**

Each file is unique, so you can easily check where the file has moved in the new structure.

Walk the JSON tree, and fill a `HashMap<String,File>`, with each leaf of the tree:

```
map.put(filename, new File(filepath));
```

Do this for the input and the output data. Then you have two maps. Then you can applies the moves:

```
for(Entry<String,File> entry : inputMap.entrySet()){
   File f = outputMap.get(entry.getKey());
   if(! f.equals(entry.getValue())){
      moveFile(entry.getValue(), f);
   }
}
```

**2 - If non-unique file names: Adding identifier**

If names are not unique then you cannot identify files with their name unambiguously. The solution is to add an identifier. This can be just a simple number that you increment when building the JSON table. Then you file entries would look like that:

```
{
     "path": "src/modules/abc/module/layouts/abc-layout.js",
     "name": "abc-layout.js",
     "type": "file"
     "id": "42"
}
```

Your Swing GUI must keep track of these ids, and return a JSON data accordingly.

Then you can apply **solution 1** except you replace `HashMap<String,File>` by `HashMap<Integer,File>`.

**3- Tracking file moves**

As proposed by @vanOekel, if this a possibility for you, make you Swing GUI keep track of the moves and return these.

A "move" can be as simple as:

```
public class Move {
   public File source, dest;
}
```

And be represented in JSON accordingly:

```
{
    "source" : "/somewhere/on/the/disk/file.ext"
    "dest" : "/elsewhere/on/the/disk/file.ext" 
}
```

Then you can rebuild the list of moves on the server by walking this JSON data, and apply the moves easily:

```
for(Move move : listOfMoves)
   moveFile(move.source, move.dest);
```