# Jackson deserialize json array to method parameters

Tags: java, json, jackson

Input json: `["Test", 0, {name:"Henry", age:12}]`

Types in the array are random, I want to map it to parameters of a method

I can get parameter types by using `method.getParameterTypes()`

I have tried this:

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = getJsonMapper();

        String[] jsonArg = mapper.readValue(json, String[].class);

        Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();

        if (jsonArg.length != params.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong args length");

        Object[] args = new Object[params.length];

        for (int i = 0;i < jsonArg.length;i++) {
            args[i] = mapper.readValue(jsonArg[i], params[i]);
        }

        method.invoke(obj, args); //Invoke Method
```

And it will throw a JsonMappingException as it isn't a string array

How can I map it to the method parameter?

Comment: There is not enough detail here, please show us what you've tried and define your issue more clearly.

Comment: I added some codes, maybe it can help you to understand what I am doing

Comment: Why not just map it to an Object list and then cast the objects into your specific types?

Comment: It will throw ClassCastException when deserializing json inside the array As it is a LinkedHashMap

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526030/how-do-you-tree-walk-json-via-jackson-2-jsonnode , I think you can crawl the json structure as described here and conditionally call your method at whatever specific points you need to.